# Publishing Excel Named Ranges to SharePoint Programmatically

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have an excel file with named ranges saved in a document library in SharePoint. I created some excel web access web parts in order to display the excel files I have. My problem is I can't seem to find a way to publish my excel files so that only the named ranges will show up.

I know this can be done manually by setting the browser view options when saving it to SharePoint but I need to do it via code because I need to run it on multiple SharePoint sites.

I was checking Visio services and saw that it had `ServerPublishOptions` I was wondering if Excel service have something similar that I can use. I was also looking at `PublishObjects` of excel interop but I'm not sure if it will address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This code select a range and insert into a sharepoint List using ADO, it is a easy way for me.

```
Public Const strSharePointInfo = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=http://sharepoint.server.com/Path/;LIST={12312456-124A-78BC-B8E7-1E526B74A015};"

Sub InsertRecordSetOnSharePoint(Rg as Range,ShtName as String)
'Bruno Leite
'http://officevb.com

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection 'Conexao para a Lista do SharePoint
Dim i As Integer,SQL as string


'sql to insert
SQL = "INSERT INTO [LISTNAME] (SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;DATABASE=" & ShtName & "].["& rg.name &"$])"

'open connection
cn.Open strSharePointInfo

'run SQL
cn.Execute SQL

Set cn = Nothing

Debug.Print "Insert OK"

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are missing the point of my post. What I'm trying to figure  out how to publish via excel services to mimic the way it is done using the client.